# Detecting a pause of 2 Seconds or more in Speech

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, transcription

is there any reliable and consistent method to detect a pause of more than 2 seconds in `AssemblyAi` realtime transcript.

https://www.assemblyai.com/docs/guides/real-time-streaming-transcription

currently my implementation is this.

```
if(currentFinalTranscript.audio_start - previousFinalTranscript.audio_end  >= 2000){
    console.log("pause greater than 2 seconds detected");
}
```

this works well when the pause duration is `5000` instead of `2000`.
but the more near i go to 2000 it starts getting unreliable.

i am assuming that the `audio_start` and `audio_end` in the realtimeTranscript response excludes the milliseconds where the person was silent.
as this seems to be the case when the pause is longer.

> currentFinalTranscript is the finalTranscript recieved in the new `socket.onMessage`

> previousFinalTranscript is the finalTranscript recieved in the preceeding `socket.onMessage` callback

other logical approaches or flaws in the current logic are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully tackled this issue. The logic was to check for a specific number of empty Partial Transcript. If the number of concurrent empty Partial Transcript exceeds the threshold number. Then i declare that a pause is detected.

Then i can adjust the threshold number to approximately guess the time of silence.

The solution is quite obvious. Just at that time i didn't think it would work.